# Why 1000 reputation points are needed to view vote counts?

Tags: discussion, voting

I was reading privileges on [this page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) and I learned that you can see vote counts and expanded usercard at 1000 reputation points.

[image]

**Why it's so expensive to obtain this privilege ?**

Comment: Note that while you don't have this privilege you could use [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) userscript to view them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/why-is-it-a-privilege-to-view-vote-counts):

> because it's "expensive" to view the vote count (in terms of running the query)

That is, with a vote table as massive as StackExchange's, allowing all users to make requests to view vote totals would put too much stress on the system. The rep requirement decreases this stress.

Comment: that's odd you would have thought that the query could execute once and then the result could be cached until it changes

Answer (score -6):

Because the system works that way, system-wide, across all SE sites. For better or worse.

Comment: Should my question include what you just said ?  " Why it's so expensive to obtain this privilege, system-wide, across all SE sites ? "